# Is there a clean way to get only string literals from a regex using Java?

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I am working in Java/Groovy and have a bunch of regular expressions that I need to test for invalid characters. But those characters appear in some of the wildcards, character classes, and escaping, so I would like to pull those out.

So for example I'd like to extract, `abc` from `\d{4}abc.*` and `\123` from `\\123`, etc.

Is there a library out there or a better way to approach this than using some hackey regular expressions myself?

NOTE: I am not suggestion that some of these regular expressions are invalid AS REGULAR EXPRESSIONS. Rather they represent strings that may violate external constraints.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to check regular expression syntax? Are these REs user input, or what?

Comment: maybe it's enough to `Pattern.compile` to validate expression ?